# vagrant path to shell script windows

Tags: vagrant

There is a problem with the path to a shell script on windows. 
On linux, the Vagrantfile works fine.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.name = "studstat_dev"
  end
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8888
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 15432
  # Provisioning mit Shell-Script
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "studstat.sh"
end
```

studstat.sh

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# Edit the following to change the name of the database user that will be created:
APP_DB_USER=vagrant
APP_DB_PASS=vagrant
# Edit the following to change the name of the database that is created (defaults to the user name)
APP_DB_NAME=studstat
# Edit the following to change the version of PostgreSQL that is installed
PG_VERSION=9.4
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
PG_REPO_APT_SOURCE=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
if [ ! -f "$PG_REPO_APT_SOURCE" ]
then
# Add PG apt repo:
echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main" > "$PG_REPO_APT_SOURCE"
# Add PGDG repo key:
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
fi
# Update package list and upgrade all packagesini
apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade
# install packages for postgres + python3
apt-get -y install "postgresql-$PG_VERSION" "postgresql-contrib-$PG_VERSION"
apt-get -y install vim git python3-setuptools python3-dev libpq-dev python3-pip
# install virtualenv via pip3, not yet in ubuntu repository (20.11.15)
pip3 install virtualenv
PG_CONF="/etc/postgresql/$PG_VERSION/main/postgresql.conf"
PG_HBA="/etc/postgresql/$PG_VERSION/main/pg_hba.conf"
PG_DIR="/var/lib/postgresql/$PG_VERSION/main"
# Edit postgresql.conf to change listen address to '*':
sed -i "s/#listen_addresses = 'localhost'/listen_addresses = '*'/" "$PG_CONF"
# Append to pg_hba.conf to add password auth:
echo "host    all             all             all                     md5" >> "$PG_HBA"
# Explicitly set default client_encoding
echo "client_encoding = utf8" >> "$PG_CONF"
# generate locales
locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
# Restart so that all new config is loaded:
service postgresql restart
cat << EOF | su - postgres -c psql
-- Create the database user:
CREATE USER $APP_DB_USER WITH PASSWORD '$APP_DB_PASS';
-- Create the database:
CREATE DATABASE $APP_DB_NAME WITH OWNER=$APP_DB_USER
                              LC_COLLATE='de_DE.UTF-8'
                              LC_CTYPE='de_DE.UTF-8'
                              ENCODING='UTF8'
                              TEMPLATE=template0;
EOF
```

The script is in the same folder as the Vagrantfile. Relevant output of vagrant shell:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: C:Users/hema0004/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20160201-2732-1v2m7qa.sh
==> default: gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes, that this means the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong.
```

The given path to log does not exist on my mashine.
Without shell script, vagrant works fine, any ideas?

[Edit]: I can access the machine but I can not execute the script from within the machine:

```
 /bin/sh: 0: Illegal option -
```

Thx, martin

Comment: can you confirm the box has access to internet when windows is the host ? does it work if you ssh without script and runs the script afterwards ?

Comment: ok I can access the machine but I can not run the script:
    /bin/sh: 0: Illegal option -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the box had no access to the internet because of missing environment variables. These variables should have been provided via the vagrant-proxyconf plugin. The underlaying problem was, that path to $VAGRANT_HOME where the proxy configuration is provided was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

can you try from the following repo

```
# Add PGDG repo key:
apt-get install -y ca-certificates wget
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
```

Comment: the script is not running when the box is in a windows host:  
/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option -

Comment: weird ... can you try changing `#!/bin/sh -e` to `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`